# When can one create a "zusammengesetzes Nomen"? When should one use genitive or prepositions instead?

Tags: grammar, noun, compound, genitive

Long words is one of my favorite features in German. Is there a criterion, *"eine grammatische Empfehlung!*, to know when we can put nouns together?

I'm not talking about creating significant words like "*Glühbirne*" or "*Pusteblumen*", don't even care if they are going to be used. I just want to know when it is correct, and when it is better than using `Genitiv`, prepositions or *Relativsätze* instead.

> 1. *Importbananen* instead of *Bananen zu importieren*, *Bananen, die man importiert*.
> 2. *Erziehungcampseinrichtung* instead of *Einrichtung der Erziehungcamps* or *Einrichtung von Erziehungcamps*.

Does the answer rely on how often they are going to be used in the text?

**Context:** (*read this text if the question wasn't clear enough.*) I was writing a text, a little essay without other value than exercising German. I had to mention some *"Verhütungsmaßnahmen gegen Jugendkriminalität"*. I have a very good teacher, and she always corrects minimal details and improves sentences whenever there is a better way to write. I was surprised when my word "*Jugendkriminalitätsverhütungsmaßnahme*" was *not* rejected after she read my text. I don't know if she overlooked it, she didn't even understand, or if I was indeed allowed to write that nonexistent word. In any case, I think that the question makes sense.

Comment: Zusammengesetzte Wörter sind genauso erlaubt wie Zahlen, die aus Ziffern zusammengesetzt sind, auch wenn nirgends explizit erlaubt wird die Zahl 234534709803098059981 zu benutzn. Dass diese nicht existent sei kann man nicht sagen, und so kann man nicht sagen, dass die Jugendkriminalitätsverhütungsmaßnahme nicht existent sei. Aber Bananen, die man importiert sind Importbananen, während der Vorgang Bananenimport heißt.

Comment: @userunknown danke, ich habe schon es geändert.

Comment: Ja, aber nun ist es in die andere Richtung falsch. Der Import ist, genauer betrachtet, ein Bananenimport, aber das importierte Obst ist, mangels besseren Klimas, eine Importbanane.

Comment: Oberaffengeil. Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaft etc.

Comment: The question [What is the longest German word (that is used)?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3802/1224) has been closed as not constructive but the comments might give you an idea of what, in theory, is possible in the German language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build “zusammengesetzte Nomen” which are as long as you want. One example for that (we played around with that in elementary school) is the “Oberweserdampfschifffahrtskapitänskajütentür”. So your “Jugendkriminalitätsverhütungsmaßnahme” is perfectly fine.

That said, as a native German speaker, I would probably not use this word. It is too long and too hard to grasp on first glance. At least, I would use a hyphen to “mark” the two parts of the word (“Jugendkriminalitäts-Verhütungsmaßnahme”) but more likely I would split it into “Verhütungsmaßnahmen gegen Jugendkriminalität”.

So in the end, it is definitely correct and you can use it. It's just that the other variant is easier to read and grasp.

Comment: I can perfectly imagine the word in a legal document... but in daily life I agree... people wouldn't really write that

Comment: Yes, that is probably true. But the language used in legal documents is a different language anyway ;-)

Comment: Just a small addition: technically, it is good style to use a hyphen if the compound noun exceeds ten syllables, as well as in any of the situations in §45 AmtlRR.